# What should I do with a question that has an exact duplicate closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I found a question which IMO has an exact duplicate. But the duplicate has been closed as off-topic. So what's the preferred approach:

- Flag the question as duplicate of the closed question?
- Flag the question as off-topic?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question and its duplicate please?

Comment: Is the question off-topic? You could vote to close the current question as off-topic as well...

Comment: For example, i just flagged your question as off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag it as a duplicate of the other question.

Who knows? Some day that other question might get re-opened. But if one question is an obvious duplicate of another, it should be marked thus.